# What apps use ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: bash

I accidentally deleted my ~/.bash_profile, and want to know which apps will go down. What most common apps (development apps) use this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, none of them should use it, since it is a bash-related file, and it won't be sourced/loaded if another shell is used.

Be sure to add the following line to a new `~/.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Loads the default .profile
```